# accepts only numbers and number should not start with 0 Angular 4

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

I am new to angular 4 ,Here I need to validate a form field which should allow only numbers and the first digit of the number should not start with 0.

I tried some solutions which related to my need but nothing is worked for me.

can anyone help me to solve this .

app.component.ts

```
NumberOnly(event: any) {
    const pattern = /^([1-9][0-9]*|0)$/;
    let inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    if (!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
      event.preventDefault();

    }
  }
```

which allows only numbers but it failed to validate the first digit is ZERO.

Comment: Try `^[1-9][0-9]*$` without the alternation.

Comment: it's not accepting 0 in any position @Thefourthbird

Comment: Try Regex: `/^(?:(?:[1-9][0-9]*)|0)$/` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EkVVni/1)

Comment: @Zhu Can you check this example https://regex101.com/r/kZBqUL/1.

Comment: @Thefourthbird's regex is right and provide the desired output.

Comment: @Matt.G not working

Comment: @Zhu, could you add the values that are not working to the demo link in my comment?

Comment: @Zhu Why not use event.target.value and then validate

Comment: @Zhu Did you see the example? Is that not what you are trying to match? https://ideone.com/bhG8xI

Comment: this is what I am looking for for me it's not allow me to enter the ZERO ,accepts only 1-9 . @Thefourthbird

Comment: I have applied that pattern in the above function but it's not working as in the sample URL @Thefourthbird

Comment: @Zhu Can you add a few examples to your question what should and what should not match? And perhaps do a `console.log(inputChar);` to see what the values are.

Comment: okay will update @Thefourthbird

Answer (score -1):

Try Regex: `/^(?:(?:[1-9][0-9]*)|0)$/`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EkVVni/1)

Comment: Brother it's accepting zero in the first position @Matt.G

Comment: I assumed you wanted to match if it is just 0, and if it is 012, it shouldn't match. If you donot want 0 to be the first digit, @The fourth bird 's answer should work